# Exportar GridView a Excel

Tags: asp.net

Intento exporter mi `GridView` a un archive en `Excel` pero me marca error al momento de dar clic en el boton para exportar, aunque dice que debe estar en un `Form with runat="server"`, el `GridView` esta en un `form`

Me marca este error:

> Control 'ctl00_Grv_main' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Estos son los `Using`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
```

Este es mi `BackEnd`:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            /// this is needed to render your new control.
            base.Render(writer);
        }
```

Esta es la function:

```
private void ExportGridToExcel()
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.Charset = "";
            string FileName = "RepoToolMaint" + DateTime.Now + ".xls";
            StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment:filename=" + FileName);
            Grv_main.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
            Grv_main.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
            Grv_main.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
            Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
```

Y este el boton donde llamo la function

```
protected void Download_repo(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ExportGridToExcel();
        }
```

Este es el `HTML`:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="modal fade" id="History-Maint" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header" style="padding: 35px 50px;">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>&nbsp Maintenance Report</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <asp:GridView ID="Grv_main"
                            CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
                            runat="server"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            Width="940px"
                            HorizontalAlign="Center"
                            DataKeyNames="id"
                            AllowPaging="True" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id" Visible="false">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_id" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="status">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_stats" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("STATUS") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="tool">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_tool" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TOOL") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Area Change">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_areach" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AREA") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="responsable">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_resp" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RESPONSABLE") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="nota">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_note" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NOTA") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="fecha de modificacion">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_mod" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MODIFY") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text='Guardar' OnClick="Download_repo" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: podrias compartir tu html tambien?

Comment: @LuisAcuña listo :D

Comment: Estas usando masterPage? ese form hace parte de la masterpage o es un formulario que muestras dentro de la masterpage?

Comment: @LuisAcuña efectivamente esta en la master page

Answer (score 1):

Pues no especificas si ese `form` hace parte del html de una `masterpage` o de un `webform` "comun".
Si estas usando un `MasterPage`, este debe tener un `<form></form>` dentro....y el contenido de los formularios que mostraras a travez de MasterPage debe estar dentro de ese `form` lo cual se hace a traves del `contentPlaceHolder`por tanto, este tambien debe estar dentro del  de tu master page... asi:

```
<html>
  ...
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <h1>Soy un MasterPage!</h1>
      <asp:contentplaceholder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
    </form>
  </body>
  ...
</html>
```

SI ya tu masterpage contiene un `<form>` no hace falta agregarlo al contenido del WebForm que intentas visualizar a traves del contentPLaceHolder de tu masterpage.

Verifica inicialmente que no estes usando 2 etiquetas `form` (una en tu `masterpage` y otra en tu `webform`)

Comment: He verificado lo que me has indicado, y efectivamente, tengo todo de esa manera, el `contentPlaceHolder` esta dentro de la etiqueta `form`